# When opening Terminal: "NO LOGINS: System going down at 01:10"

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, terminal.app

I'm trying to get a terminal open, and I get this message:

```
NO LOGINS: System going down at 01:10

Login incorrect
login: *myname*
Login incorrect
login:
```

It doesn't prompt for my password. This happens with iTerm2 and Terminal.

I'm using `zsh`, and when I change my default command to `bash` it runs fine. Is it possible to get a `zsh` session open?

Comment: Are you sure this is connected with your login shell? (How can you chage it when you can't login?) I would expect that if the systeme is scheduled for going down shortly that all logins except root are disabled.

Comment: @mpy in the iTerm (and I think terminal) prefs you can set the command that runs when a terminal is opened.

Comment: Try moving your ~/.zshrc file and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but I resolved it by deleting the file `nologin` inside the `/etc/` folder.

Perhaps here is some explanation, from the book *A Practical Guide to UNIX for Mac OS X Users*, by Mark G. Sobell and Peter Seebach:

> The **pam_nologin** module makes sure that if the **/etc/nologin** file exists, only the **root** user is allowed to log in. (That is, the **pam_nologin** module reports success only if **/etc/nologin** does not exist or if the **root** user is logging in.) Thus, when a shutdown has been scheduled in the near future, the system administrator can keep users from logging in on the system only to experience a shutdown moments later.